# How to capture an image with same aspect ratio as that of the preview shown

Tags: java, android, android-camerax

I've been using the CameraX library for capturing images of specifically having aspect ratio of 4:3 but it doesn't work and to be more specific even after specifying same aspect ratio for capture and preview the image saved have different aspect ratio as that what is shown in preview.

This is the code I've written

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ListenableFuture<ProcessCameraProvider> cameraProviderFuture;
    PreviewView previewView;
    private ImageCapture imageCapture;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        previewView = findViewById(R.id.previewView);

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, 101);
        } else {
            initializeCamera();
        }


    }

    private void initializeCamera() {
        cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this);
        cameraProviderFuture.addListener(() -> {
            try {
                ProcessCameraProvider cameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get();
                startCameraX(cameraProvider);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(MainActivity.this));
    }

    private void startCameraX(ProcessCameraProvider cameraProvider) {
        cameraProvider.unbindAll();

        CameraSelector cameraSelector = new CameraSelector.Builder()
                .requireLensFacing(CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_FRONT)
                .build();

        Preview preview = new Preview.Builder()
                .setTargetAspectRatio(AspectRatio.RATIO_4_3)
                .build();

        // Calculate the crop rectangle to achieve the desired preview area
        Rect cropRect = calculateCropRect(previewView.getWidth(), previewView.getHeight());

        // Set the size of the PreviewView to match the crop rectangle dimensions
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = previewView.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.width = cropRect.width();
        layoutParams.height = cropRect.height();
        previewView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

        preview.setSurfaceProvider(previewView.getSurfaceProvider());

        preview.setSurfaceProvider(previewView.getSurfaceProvider());

        // Use the same crop rect for ImageCapture
        imageCapture = new ImageCapture.Builder()
                .setCaptureMode(ImageCapture.CAPTURE_MODE_MINIMIZE_LATENCY)
                .setTargetAspectRatio(AspectRatio.RATIO_4_3)
                .setTargetRotation(getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation())
                .build();


        cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(this, cameraSelector, preview, imageCapture);
    }

    private Rect calculateCropRect(int width, int height) {
        int viewWidth = previewView.getWidth();
        int viewHeight = previewView.getHeight();
        // Define the desired aspect ratio for the crop
        double targetAspectRatio = 4.0 / 3.0;

        // Calculate the crop height and width based on the target aspect ratio
        int cropWidth;
        int cropHeight;
        if (viewWidth / (double) viewHeight > targetAspectRatio) {
            cropHeight = viewHeight;
            cropWidth = (int) (viewHeight * targetAspectRatio);
        } else {
            cropWidth = viewWidth;
            cropHeight = (int) (viewWidth / targetAspectRatio);
        }

        // Calculate the offset to center the crop window
        int xOffset = (viewWidth - cropWidth) / 2;
        int yOffset = (viewHeight - cropHeight) / 2;

        // Create the crop rectangle
        return new Rect(xOffset, yOffset, xOffset + cropWidth, yOffset + cropHeight);
    }

    public void onCaptureButtonClick(View view) {
        capturePicture();
    }

    private void capturePicture() {
        long timeStamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, "IMG_" + timeStamp);
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");

        ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions outputFileOptions = new ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions.Builder(
                getContentResolver(),
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                contentValues
        ).build();

        imageCapture.takePicture(
                outputFileOptions,
                ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this), // Executor for handling callbacks
                new ImageCapture.OnImageSavedCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onImageSaved(@NonNull ImageCapture.OutputFileResults outputFileResults) {
                        runOnUiThread(() -> {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Photo saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        });
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(@NonNull ImageCaptureException exception) {
                        // Image capture error handling
                        runOnUiThread(() -> {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error: " + exception.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        });
                    }
                });
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == 101) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                initializeCamera();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I cannot exactly pin point what could be the problem please let me know my mistake since I'm just a beginner and still learning. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use [LifecycleCameraController](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/view/LifecycleCameraController), ImageCapture will crop for you. Similarly you can put your Preview and ImageCapture in the same [UseCaseGroup](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/core/UseCaseGroup).

Just be aware that cropping takes time and it adds latency to your capture.